# Не отображаются элементы с базы данных phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<?php   
    $book_id = $_GET\['authors_id'\];
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql','BookCatalog');

    if(!$link){
        echo "ERROR!";
    }
    //if(!is_numeric($book_id)) exit();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>id_1</title>
<?php
    function tableGetComponent($book_id)
    {
        global $link;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_book WHERE IdBook=".$book_id;
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $authors = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);


        return $authors;
    }
?>
<?php $getComponent = tableGetComponent($book_id); ?>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1><? echo $getComponent\['BookName'\]?> </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?=$getComponent\['Description'\]?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[image: Картинка]

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что проблема кроется к самому вызову функции.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function tableGetComponent($book_id)
    {
        global $link;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_book WHERE IdBook = $book_id";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $authors = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        return $authors;
    }
?>
```